# Exporting a Google Worksheet using REST in .net client environment

Tags: .net, webclient, google-drive-api, webrequest

Im looking for a way to programmatically get informations (last modification time) and then export and download a Google Sheets file to cvs format.

I already found a way to do this from the browser:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?
key={GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_KEY}&hl&exportFormat=csv&gid={REQUESTED_SHEET_NUMBER}
```

Where GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_KEY and REQUESTED_SHEET_NUMBER can be read from the browser bar during standard navigation.

but obviously my browser is autenticated by a cookie and i'm not sure how to reproduce this situation in a console application.

The reason i would like to avoid using Google Drive SDK or Google Spreadsheet SDK is the lack of source code and as such i would not be able to port the application using Mono.

Update:
I managed to access my file **setting the sharing to public view access from Drive**, this works fine for my purpose and i'd like to share it, even if it's not a full solution if you wish to keep file view access to private.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var file_id = GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_KEY;
    var sheet_number=REQUESTED_SHEET_NUMBER;
    var export_format="csv";
    string unf_url="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={0}&hl&gid={1}&exportFormat={2}";
    string url = string.Format(unf_url, file_id, sheet_number, export_format);

    var request=WebRequest.Create(url);
    var result=request.BeginGetResponse(handleResponse,request);
    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void handleResponse(IAsyncResult arg)
{
    var request = (arg.AsyncState as WebRequest);
    var stream = request.EndGetResponse(arg).GetResponseStream();
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());   
    }
}
```

Update 2: This seems to be **working only with the recent GSheets updated sheet format** (offline sheets). So if you see a "ccc" in the url you need to copy the content to a brand new file.

Comment: What do you mean by lack or source code? Drive api works from anywjere you can do an https request.

Comment: I had mispelled Google Drive Api for Google Drive Sdk, fixing now

Comment: its neither in this case. its the google spreadsheets api, thou the drive api probably has a way to export directly intead of having to read the cell feed

Comment: Yes, the whole OAuth2 server flow procedure is way overkill for the problem at hand. Seems like putting the file to public access and using the get string i found before works well enough.

Comment: Yes i was going to suggest that

Comment: Guess what... old spreadsheet system didn't work like that, if you get a "ccc" instead of a "d" in the url you need to copy the ss to a brand new file or login will still be required, regardless the sharing options.